# Return newly created object after creation with ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

We have a modelViewset:

```
class ObjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = MyObjectSerializer


    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        ...

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        ...

    def perform_destroy(self, instance):
        ...
```

But perform_create [doesn't return the newly created object](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/4015) which means the 201 response only contains a few random fields that were specified during creation and not the whole new object.

Is there some special way to get the object without overriding the .create() call? It seems like returning the new object is expected behavior, so I'm worried I'm doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

It's a viewset, it needs to return HTTP response to client, from the link you posted you can access it via serializer.instance:

> You can access the object through serializer.instance

But you have to process the request and create the instance first:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    # call parent class implementation to create the instance
    response = super().perform_create(serializer)
    # now you can access it via serializer
    instance = serializer.instance
    # return the response to the client
    return response
```